# Using the ACK method with Python's Socket library

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Using Python, I need a server to receive messages from a 3rd party running on the local network. This 3rd party expects an ACK (acknowledge) response before sending the next message.

How can I send this ACK response?

Right now, I have to wait for the timeout of the 3rd party to receive the next message (10s) when I should be receiving multiple messages per second.

Here is the code used:

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('', 2000))
while True:
    socket.listen()
    client, address = socket.accept()
    print("{} connected".format( address ))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    response = client.recv(8112)
    if response != "":
```

Comment: TCP ACK is sent automatically, but perhaps they do not mean TCP ACK. What is the 3rd-party client?

Comment: The 3rd-party was developed internally with limited documentation (it states that it should receive a single byte 0x06). From the logs, I can see that it considers that the message sent didn't receive the expected ACK response.

I get the same error when adding:

socket.send(b"0x06")

Comment: >  socket.send(b"0x06")

If this should be _one_ byte, `b"\x06"` but not `b"0x06"`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not call `listen()` in the "while" loop. In BSD sockets (utilized in Python), `listen()` is to be called once to switch the socket to listening mode. I don't know specifics of your OS running this example, but, on some of them, this could result in failure. (Linux ignores repeating of listen() on an already listening socket.)

Then, it is unclear what ACK do you mean. Variants are TCP ACK and acknowledge of an own protocol over TCP. For the TCP ACK, 1) you can't really control its send; it is done automatically in the TCP implementation, and 2) it is the unlikely case, I'd expect.

If this is the specific protocol ACK, learn the protocol requirements. In your code, the definite inconsistency is that you, at the server side, don't send anything to client, but then start waiting for a "response". A response can be only to a request, but there is no request here.

In the comments, you stated server should send one byte of value 0x06; this should be done, for example, as `client.send(b"\x06")`.

If the protocol is not under NDA, you may publish its specification essentials to get aid for understanding what should be done. Sometimes, well, these specs are written in a manner suitable only for an experienced network developer.

Comment: Many thanks! It was indeed the format of the byte that needed to be `client.send(b"\x06")`.